# align icon on top of text inside button tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I align the icon inside a button tag to the top of the text, it is currently on the left side of the text. I can't figure out how.

Here is the code

```html
<div class='nav'>
  <button class="home btn">
      <i class="btnIcon fa fa-home"></i>
       <span>HOME</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: just note, you have a typo - your closing span is actually an opening span

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest method would be to just declare the span as `display:block`

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='nav'>
  <button class="home btn">
  <i class="btnIcon fa fa-home"></i>
   <span>HOME</span>
</button>
</div>
```

Or use Flexbox and column layout

```css
.btn.vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='nav'>
  <button class="home btn vertical">
  <i class="btnIcon fa fa-home"></i>
   <span>HOME</span>
</button>
</div>
```